# Selecting a Custom Column Type across all tables in a SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently, I have a query that uses the `sys` tables to return all the tables and column names where the column is a specific custom type, the query looks like this:

```
select 
    schemas.name, obj.name, col.name
from
    sys.objects obj
inner join 
    sys.columns col on col.object_id = obj.object_id
inner join 
    sys.types types on types.user_type_id = col.user_type_id 
inner join 
    sys.schemas schemas on obj.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
where 
    types.name = 'myCustomType'
```

However, the security of the SQL Server database is being changed and we can no longer query the `sys` tables. How else can I query for this information?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA views?

Comment: @SeanLange According to some of what I've read the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a view of the sys tables, so I do not believe I will have access to that functionality.

Comment: They are a view of the system tables. If you don't have access to those there really isn't much of anything you can do.

Comment: Those objects in the `sys` schema are system catalog **views** - not tables.

Comment: @SeanLange Is there some type of alternative work around? Make my own tracking table maybe?